# How do I use yeoman --force?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've got a generator that generates stuff:

```
yo blah -o . fred.txt
```

This creates file(s) in `.` based on the contents of `fred.txt`.

I'd like this to run as part of my build process, so that when I update `fred.txt` yeoman is re-run to regenerate the outputs.

When I try this by hand, though, yeoman always tells when if the new file differs from the old one, and waits for input. This is no use as part of a build process. The help page suggests that `--force` would be just the ticket, so I've tried that:

```
yo --force true blah -o . fred.txt
```

It still asks the question though. So I also tried this:

```
yo blah --force true -o . fred.txt
```

That didn't make any difference. When the new output is different from the old output, it stops and waits for me to press a key.

Can I just make it overwrite the file, no questions asked?

(The build process will run yeoman as if it were being run from the command line.)

Comment: `yo blah -o . fred.txt --force`? Not sure why you've got `true` thrown in there.

Comment: That works, thanks. Please post as an answer and I'll be glad to accept it. As for why `--force true` - as far as I can tell, the rules are that if a bool switch isn't followed immediately by another switch, or the end of the command line, its value must be supplied. So I've been in the habit of always doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
yo blah -o . fred.txt --force
```

There's no need to explicitly state `true`. Generally, if the flag exists, it is treated as Boolean `true` by default.